# return multiple dataframe from scala function in Try block

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

i have a function in scala as below and need to return two dataframes and matcherror if any problem

```
 def createDF(dataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame Or Every[Problem] = {
       val (p,d) = Try({
          dataFrame
            .groupBy($"id", $"level", $"cust_id", $"p_type_id",$"P_Type")
            .agg(sum($"x") ,
              sum($"y") )
            .filter($"start_date" between ($"sDateRange", $"eDateRange"))

          dataFrame
            .groupBy($"id", $"level", $"cust_id", $"p_type_id",$"P_Type")
            .agg(sum($"x") ,
              sum($"y") )
            .filter($"s_date" between ($"sDateRange", $"eDateRange"))
        )
        (p,d) match {
          case Success(p,d) => Good(p,d)
          case Failure(problem) => {
            log.error("createDF failed", problem)
            Bad(One(Problem("createDF")))
          }
        }
      }
```

}

I am getting the below error

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; [error] found : (T1, T2) [error] required: scala.util.Try[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] 


wrong number of arguments for pattern scala.util.Success[Any](value: Any) [error] case Success(p,d) => Good(p,d)
```

However,the above code is not working and giving error .Can anyone please help me

Comment: Please provide the error message you are receiving.

Comment: these are the errors :

constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : (T1, T2)
[error]  required: scala.util.Try[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]











 wrong number of arguments for pattern scala.util.Success[Any](value: Any)
[error]       case Success(p,d) => Good(p,d)

Comment: Is the code syntactically correct, because the brackets are not synchronized. Could you check and update it? Then we could help you better.

Comment: Please add your error to the question body, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning a tuple of dataframes from the try that's why  you are getting the wrong number of arguments exception. Also your function only expects one dataframe to return on success. I've simplified it here so that it's easier to see usage.

```
 def createDF(dataFrame: DataFrame): (DataFrame,DataFrame)   = {
   val pd = Try({
     val df1 = dataFrame //do ops
     val df2 = dataFrame //do other ops
     (df1, df2)
   }
      )
     pd   match {
        case Success(v) => v
        case Failure(problem) =>
          //handle or throw
          throw new Exception("handle error")
        }
    }
```

Comment: def createDF(dataFrame: DataFrame): (DataFrame,DataFrame)  or Every[Problem] = {
   val pd = Try({
     val df1 = dataFrame //do ops
     val df2 = dataFrame //do other ops
     (df1, df2)
   }
      )
     pd   match {
        case Success(v) => v
        case Failure(problem) =>
          //handle or throw
          throw new Exception("handle error")
        }
    }

Comment: found   : (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])

required: org.scalactic.Or[(org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameorg.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame),org.scalactic.Every[com.shared.Problem]]
[error]     (which expands to)  org.scalactic.Or[(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]),org.scalactic.Every[com.shared.Problem]]
[error]       case Success(v) => v